# dropped connection with TLS

Tags: ssl, https, openssl

I have this command which is connecting to a TLS server:

```
openssl s_client -connect ec2-xx-xx-xx-xx.us-west-1.compute.amazonaws.com:4004 -reconnect -CAfile ryans-cert.pem
```

I get about 4 of these messages:

```
drop connection and then reconnect
CONNECTED(00000005)
```

and then it will finally connect.
Anybody know why it has to re-try a few times?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`-reconnect` option of openssl s_client tries to reconnect to the same Server 5 times.

This is done primarily to check if the said Server supports `Session Resumption` feature of SSL/TLS. One of the methods to support the Session Resumption feature is to enable Session Cache on the Server. This option checks if Session Cache is enabled on the Server.

Refer to [RFC 5246](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc5246) (TLS 1.2) to understand more in-detail about how TLS Session Resumption works.

Comment: so reconnect will always reconnect 5 times? it doesn't seem to do it for a locally running server only remote server

Comment: openssl s_client always reconnects it for 5 times. It is also mentioned in their documentation. Not sure why it doesn't do it for locally running server (assuming your test is correct). Session Resumption should be supported by a Server for even local clients and from that perspective, it should be supported.

Answer (score 0):

> ```
> openssl s_client  ... -reconnect ...
> ...
> drop connection and then reconnect
> CONNECTED(00000005)
> ```
>
> Anybody know why it has to re-try a few times?

From [the documentation of s_client](https://www.openssl.org/docs/manmaster/man1/s_client.html):

> -reconnect
> Reconnects to the same server 5 times using the same session ID, this can be used as a test that session caching is working.

Thus, the re-tries you see is what you explicitly asked for by using `-reconnect`.

Comment: how important is it to test that session caching is working? why does it only do this for remote connections not connections to localhost?

Comment: @MrCholo: I have no idea how you've tested but `-reconnect` does its documented behavior even when connecting to localhost, I've just tried it. The question about the importance of session caching is outside of your original question, i.e. is a new question and should not be asked in a comment. But in short: it is relevant for performance both in terms of latency (one less round trip for the SSL handshake) and computing costs.